# How do I write to localStorage from Java on Android

Tags: android

I am looking into the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.html API but it does not support writing to localStorage from Java. What I would like to do is to store data from the Java side of an android application to be read by the JavaScript side of the app.

For instance, in JavaScript I can use localStorage.getItem(), localStorage.setItem(). However, I cannot find similar API to accomplish the task from Java. Is there a workaround or it has not been implemented by the Android platform yet?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: localStorage is a web browser thing and thus it's only going to be accessible to code running in the browser. You could extend the classes in WebView so you can essentially pass the request through the browser to underlying Java code or use something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to access device APIs in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to store data in an Android application, as detailed in the [Storage Options guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html):

- [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) - simple key/value pairs specific to your application. This is probably the closest to WebStorage.
- [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) - read/write files
- [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) - SD card file storage
- [Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) - better for large amounts of structured data
- [Network](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#netw) - obviously, you can store/retrieve data remotely if needed

Comment: None of these would work, because none of these are SOP protected. That's exactly why I want to write to localStorage.

Comment: If SharedPreferences, which can only be accessed by your own application and not directly by any user, do not qualify, then you should not be storing anything on the device from the Java side.

Comment: SharedPreferences do not qualify because they cannot be accessed from JavaScript in a SOP protected manner. Thanks for the suggestion, though!